# I want to ping the emulater from the server through LAN or WIFI

Tags: android

I want to ping the emulator from the server through LAN or WIFI can an one tell the procedure it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported.

First, ping is ICMP traffic which the emulator forwards don't support.

Second, the emulator forwards only accept traffic on the host's loopback interface, not its external interfaces - ie, you can only directly contact the emulator from within the PC it's running on.

If you wanted to use a supported format such as TCP, you could write a daemon that runs on the PC and forwards traffic from the external interface to the port on the internal that's then forwarded into the emulator.

Pretty much the only time you can directly contact an android device is when it's an actual hardware device sitting on the same wifi network or LAN as the machine that wants to contact it; not when it's an emulator and not when it's a phone on a mobile network.

Comment: If server broad cast some thing through wifi how to read that message and display in mobile

Comment: And my application is like this 1) the server will send some message through wifi. 2)I want listen to it and the i want to display the message

Comment: It's generally better to design your system so that the device contacts the server rather than the other way around, as a server can only connect to a device in the special case of wifi.  One means for servers to notify clients in the real world is Android C2DM (cloud to device messaging).  In the wifi case you might be able to use a UDP broadcast, but I have memories of people reporting difficulty with that on android.